# Django Admin custom format field

Tags: django, django-models

Code snippets:

```
class HighscoreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'score')
    ...
```

and

```
class Highscore(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    ...
```

Question:

Let's say we have a score value of 100000. In Admin, it will display the score as 1000000, but what if I want a different format?  How would you change the format to output -> 1,000,000?

I heard that you could add a method to the Highscore class something like foo_display, where foo is the field in question:

```
def score_display(self):
    """ returns scores with commas as thousands separators in the admin display """
   return '{:,}'.format(self.score)
```

Comment: This has been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216764/in-the-django-admin-site-how-do-i-change-the-display-format-of-time-fields) before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In the Django admin site, how do I change the display format of time fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216764/in-the-django-admin-site-how-do-i-change-the-display-format-of-time-fields)

Comment: @ferrix Not the duplicate of that post.

Comment: For those still interested, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203089/make-django-forms-use-comma-as-decimal-separator).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NUMBER_GROUPING](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-NUMBER_GROUPING) and [USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR) in `settings.py`:

```py
USE_L10N = True

USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True
NUMBER_GROUPING = 3
```

(Also check [THOUSAND_SEPARATOR](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-THOUSAND_SEPARATOR) and [DECIMAL_SEPARATOR](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-DECIMAL_SEPARATOR).)