# How to change time input format in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-timezone

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#time-input-formats) describe the use of `TIME_INPUT_FORMATS`, and say that the formats are described using the [Python datetime module syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

But in Django Admin 4.2 none of the directives - I'm using  `%H, %M, %I, %p` - are making any difference.  Instead, only 24-hour time inputs are accepted, with and without leading zeros.

How do I gain control over the format, preferably without altering admin templates?

Here are the other relevant settings:

*settings.py*

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Denver'
USE_TZ = True
USE_I18N = False
```

There's the [input_formats](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateTimeField.input_formats) argument for DateTimeField, but that includes date formats, and I need just the time formats separately (for a Django Admin detail view of an object that has a `datetime` field).

There's also [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216764/in-the-django-admin-site-how-do-i-change-the-display-format-of-time-fields) about *display* of times that looks interesting, but I'm concerned now with time *input*.