Change DateField Input format on django admin edit page
I have a Django project where users can submit requests and then our admin's can view these requests through Django's admin page. I'd like the TimeField on the change page to be in a different format when one our our admins selects an object to change. The image below show what a list of objects looks like through the list display page. The Start time is in a 12 hour format using AM/PM.

Once the user clicks an object to change though the form expects the the Start Time to be in 24 hour format as shown below.

I'd like to change the admin form to match the list display format if possible.
If I need to provide any other information or code example please let me know.
Thank you.

seems very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216764/in-the-django-admin-site-how-do-i-change-the-display-format-of-time-fields
